Is there an online community more focused on the (sensory) motor system (and biomechanics)?
I really like this group and stackoverflow in general but only few questions here are on the motor system (12 tags for motor!). Are there any other good groups to check out?
I've found reddit.com/r/biomechanics but there are hardly any discussions. 
Im currently learning about human sensory motor control research, which I want to apply to rehabilitation. So I am reading books like Shadmehrs [1] 
Im an engineer with an background is in humanoid robotics. 
I appreciate any pointers! 
[1] http://www.shadmehrlab.org/papers_page.html#Textbook

This site is still fairly new. So I encourage you task a few questions about the motor system to see whether you get useful answers.

Seems like this should be in meta.cogsci rather than cogsci (or closed).
